# Запись массива в json файл

Tags: php, массивы, json

Есть `html` страница с 3 `input-и type="radio"`(один из  них submit), при выборе одного и нажатия на подтверждающую кнопку данные какая кнопка выбрана обрабатываются `php` скриптом и записываются в `json` файл. Но проблема в том, что когда один раз выбираешь первый а потом второй то в файл записывается вместо одной из цифр(кол-ва нажатий конкретно на этот `input`) какие-то знаки.Переменные $yes и $no меняются в зависимости от того как часто нажимали на каждую из кнопок. Вот весь код `php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="poll">
    <h3>How are you?</h3>
    <form action="script.php" method="post">
      Good:
      <input type="radio" name="vote" value="0">
      <br> Bad:
      <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот весь код `php`

```
<?php 
    $vote = $_POST['vote'];

    $filename = "data.json";
    $content = file($filename);

    $array = explode(",", $content[0]);
    $yes = isset($array[0]) ? $array[0] : 0;;
    $no = isset($array[1]) ? $array[1] : 0;;

    if ($vote == 0) {
        $yes += 1;
    }
    if ($vote == 1) {
        $no += 1;
    }

    $insertvote = 
    [
        'Good: ' => $yes, 
        'Bad: ' => $no
    ];
    $pretty = json_encode($insertvote, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $fp = fopen($filename,"w");
    fputs($fp,$pretty);
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

Вот вывод `json` файла

```
 {
    "Good: ": "{\n",
    "Bad: ": 1
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы не декодируете json перед использованием:

```
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true) ?: 
    ['Good' => 0, 'Bad' => 0];

if ($vote == 0) $content['Good'] += 1;
if ($vote == 1) $content['Bad'] += 1;

file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($content));
```

Comment: спасибо большое)